# Using stb-native-packager with Debian and SystemV on Play 2.6

Tags: playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have upgrade from Play! 2.6 two Play! 2,6, but now I cannot get my application deployed.

I used to have

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.archetypes.ServerLoader.SystemV
serverLoading in Debian := ServerLoader.SystemV
```

But now there is the plugin, so I added it. I thought I used SystemV, but also tried systemd. Both don't generate any of the init.d scripts it did in 2.5.

```
lazy val knockadoonserver = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean, DebianPlugin, SystemdPlugin)
```

What else do I need to do?
I have been at this for the whole day, and cannot find the solution.

Comment: What task are you using? When I run `debian:stage` it does generate the service file(s) in `target/<project>-<version>/...`

Comment: I can confirm it is working now. I have rebuild my project completely, and maybe I have changed a configuration parameter somewhere in between that changed it operation. I tried yesterday on a example project from Play! and it didn't work either, so there mightthave been an issue with an old version somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit confusing and you mixed the old and new API.

The `serverloading` setting was the old API. In the more recent version you can enable system loading types via an AutoPlugin, which you almost did correctly ( Systemd instead of SystemV ).

Here's the documentation: https://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/latest/archetypes/systemloaders.html#systemv

Cheers,
Muki

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but it started to work. Now SBT started saying:

[IJ]sbt:knockadoon> debian:packageBin
[error] No such setting/task
[error] debian:packageBin
[error] 

But it still works in activator, so that is good enough for the moment.
I will comment out the obsolete line and see on the next deployment if it is still ok, I was trying different combinations of settings at the time.